# SQL Server queries to table which name matches the command name

Tags: sql, sql-server, aliases, mssql-jdbc

```
SELECT role.name, role_privelege.privelege 
FROM role
JOIN role ON role.id = role_privelege.id
```

breaks with an error:

> [Error Code: 1013, SQL State: S0001]
>   The objects "role" and "role" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them.

With aliases it also doesn't work.

As well DbVizualizer highlights the `role` in `role.name` for example as command name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mis-typed the joined table:

```
SELECT role.name, role_privelege.privelege 
FROM role
JOIN role_privelege ON role.id = role_privelege.id
```

Comment: Ashes to my my head, I'm very sorry. All was okay from the start, misstyped privileges as priveleges. Thank you for your help